# ob_start() and ob_clean() not working

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin. I am using `ob_start()` on init `add_action` and using `ob_clean()` during my code ahead. It is working fine, but when I enable visual composer wordpress plugin, `ob_clean()` doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get errors?

Comment: NO I don't get error. but ob_clean() doesn't perform as expected.. I got all output.. ob_clean() doesn't clean buffers

Comment: I have the same problem. As a workaround I use two custom functions __ob_start() and __ob_end_clean() which wrap the original functions.